# Converting a C++ nested template structure to C#

Tags: c#, c++, templates, generics

In C++ I have a structure:

```
template <class T> class A1
{...
};

template <class T> class A2
{...
};
etc
```

I then have another nested template class structure:

```
template <class T, class A> class B : public A
{...
};

template <class T, class A> class B : public A
{...
};
etc
```

which in turn is used by another nested structure:

```
template <template <class, class> class B> class C1
{...
};

template <template <class, class> class B> class C2
{...
};
etc
```

if nested generics are not allowed in C# how would i construct this form?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint)? Sorry if not! I don't entirely understand what your code C++ represents here.

Comment: Its really more that i use templates of A in B and then use templates of B in C. A are types of calculation, B are a ways to sample A calculations, and C is a predictors that use B values.

Comment: Structures and classes are not equivalent.  A struct in c++ and c# are equivalent and are really consectuctive memory location without any bytes containing type info.  A class has object types and their values and you cannot cast one for another.  Is you c++ code managed on unmanaged?  If it is not managed than you have to use Marshal methods to copy the unmanaged memory to managed memory.

Comment: i didnt mean an actual struct, just a structure should have said class

Comment: In C# you can't derive a class from a type parameter.